# Install symfony/maker-bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-4.4

I'm dealing with an application created with `symfony 3.4` and updated to `symfony 4.4`, I need to update `doctrine/inflector` to 2.^ version to install `symfony/make-bundle`, with:

```
 composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

I get:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/maker-bundle ^1.43 -> satisfiable by symfony/maker-bundle[v1.43.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.43.0 requires doctrine/inflector ^2.0 -> found doctrine/inflector[2.0.0, ..., 2.0.4] but the package is fixed to 1.4.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle 1.4.0 requires doctrine/inflector ^2.0 -> found doctrine/inflector[2.0.0, ..., 2.0.4] but the package is fixed to 1.4.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.12.13 requires doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle[1.4.0].
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle is locked to version 1.12.13 and an update of this package was not requested.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Then I tried with :

```
 composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev -W
```

and I tried deleting `composer.lock`

But I can't install inflector v2

Comment: I think you should update `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` to the v2 version.

Comment: You could try creating a new 4.4 project and then examining the differences in composer.json.  However make sure you keep doctrine/orm at 2.11.  The 2.12 version breaks the maker bundle as well as other things.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, you should try with any compatible maker-bundle version

```
composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle:*
```